# Regular expression for string's of a's and b's beginning with b and not having two consecutive a's

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

Question: Write a regular expression for the following language:
**"All strings of a's and b's in ∑<sup>*</sup> beginning with b and not having two consecutive a's.**

A textbook says the answer is **(b+ba)<sup>*</sup>**.
Shouldn't it be **(b+ba)<sup>+</sup>** though, since if we included the star, it means we are accepting the empty string? And the empty string does not belong to the language above?

Thanks.

Comment: I concur. The empty string does not begin with $b$, so is not in the language.